# Create/Update logstash pipelines through rest apis (kibana or logtsash) with pipeline configuration (content of *.conf file) passed as body parameter

Tags: rest, logstash, kibana, elk

The most popular way of coding & deploying logstash pipelines is to create a `my_pipeline.conf` file and run it like

```
bin/logstash -f conf/my_pipeline.conf
```

Elastic offers an alternative consisting of apis:

[logstash PUT api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/logstash-api-put-pipeline.html#logstash-api-put-pipeline-example)

```bash
PUT _logstash/pipeline/my_pipeline
{
  "description": "Sample pipeline for illustration purposes",
  "last_modified": "2021-01-02T02:50:51.250Z",
  "pipeline_metadata": {
    "type": "logstash_pipeline",
    "version": "1"
  },
  "username": "elastic",
  "pipeline": "input {}\n filter { grok {} }\n output {}",
  "pipeline_settings": {
    "pipeline.workers": 1,
    "pipeline.batch.size": 125,
    "pipeline.batch.delay": 50,
    "queue.type": "memory",
    "queue.max_bytes.number": 1,
    "queue.max_bytes.units": "gb",
    "queue.checkpoint.writes": 1024
  }
}
```

as well as kibana api that also upsert the logstah pipeline

[kibana api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/logstash-configuration-management-api-create.html)

`PUT <kibana host>:<port>/api/logstash/pipeline/<id>`

```
$ curl -X PUT api/logstash/pipeline/hello-world
{
  "pipeline": "input { stdin {} } output { stdout {} }",
  "settings": {
    "queue.type": "persisted"
  }
}
```

As you can see in both apis, the **content** of the **logstash** `"pipeline.conf"`file is included in the  **"pipeline" key** of the **json body of the HTTP call**.

Basically I have dozens of *.conf pipelines files and I would like to avoid developping complex code to parse them to reformat their content with espace characters for new lines, carriage returns...

***My question is: do you know an "easy" way to feed this "pipeline" parameter in the body of the HTTP call with as little formatting transformations as possible of the original .conf files?***

To *illustrate* how complex this formatting operation might be, I have an example of what a `terraform` provider does behind the scenes to generate the right expected format *from a simple pipeline ".conf" file*.
Here is the original content of the file **logs_alerts_pubsub.conf**:

```
input {
      google_pubsub {
        project_id => "pj-becfr-monitoring-mgmt"
        topic => "f7_monitoring_topic_${environment}_alerting_eck"
        subscription => "f7_monitoring_subscription_${environment}_alerting_eck"
        json_key_file => "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash-sa.json"
        codec => "json"
      }
    }
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "application_code" => "a-alerting-eck"
    "leanix_id" => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "workfront_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "alerts-%%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    hosts => [ "${url}" ]
    user => "elastic"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    password => "${pwd}"
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt"
  }
}
```

Here is the terraform code:

```
locals {
  pipeline_list = fileset(path.root, "./modules/elasticsearch_logstash_pipeline/*.conf")
  splitpipepath = split("/", var.pipeline)
  pipename      = element(local.splitpipepath, length(local.splitpipepath) - 1)
  pipename_ex   = split(".", local.pipename)[0]
  category      = split("_", local.pipename_ex)[1]
}

resource "kibana_logstash_pipeline" "newpipeline" {
  for_each = local.pipeline_list
  name        = "tf-${local.category}-${var.environment}-${local.pipename_ex}"
  description = "Logstash Pipeline through Kibana from file"
  pipeline    = templatefile(var.pipeline, { environment = var.environment, url = var.elastic_url, pwd = var.elastic_password })
  settings = {
    "queue.type" = "persisted"
  }
}
```

And below you see the content of the `tf.state` file (focus on the **"pipeline" key**):

```
{
      "module": "module.elasticsearch_logstash_pipeline[\"modules/elasticsearch_logstash_pipeline/logs_alerts_pubsub.conf\"]",
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "kibana_logstash_pipeline",
      "name": "newpipeline",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/disaster37/kibana\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "description": "Logstash Pipeline through Kibana from file",
            "id": "tf-alerts-dev-logs_alerts_pubsub",
            "name": "tf-alerts-dev-logs_alerts_pubsub",
            "pipeline": "input {\n      google_pubsub {\n        project_id =\u003e \"pj-becfr-monitoring-mgmt\"\n        topic =\u003e \"f7_monitoring_topic_dev_alerting_eck\"\n        subscription =\u003e \"f7_monitoring_subscription_dev_alerting_eck\"\n        json_key_file =\u003e \"/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash-sa.json\"\n        codec =\u003e \"json\"\n      }\n    }\nfilter {\n  mutate {\n    add_field =\u003e { \"application_code\" =\u003e \"a-alerting-eck\"\n    \"leanix_id\" =\u003e \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\"\n    \"workfront_id\" =\u003e \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"\n    }\n  }\n}\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    index =\u003e \"alerts-gcp\"\n    hosts =\u003e [ \"https://35.187.29.254:9200\" ]\n    user =\u003e \"elastic\"\n    ssl =\u003e true\n    ssl_certificate_verification =\u003e false\n    password =\u003e \"HIDDEN\"\n    cacert =\u003e \"/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt\"\n  }\n}",
            "settings": {
              "queue.type": "persisted"
            },
            "username": "elastic"
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [
            [
              {
                "type": "get_attr",
                "value": "pipeline"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "private": "bnVsbA=="
        }
      ]
    }
```

If you have any idea of straightforward commands either in bash or in any language where I could do dump/load or encode/decode or any simple regex, as generic as possible, it would be helpful (FYI in this specific context I cannot use terraform)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to substitute the variabkes inside the `<pipeline>.conf` files as well as a way to correctly format the content of that file as json string. To restart from the beginning, here is the content of the logstash pipeline file `logs_alerts_pubsub.conf`:

```yaml
input {
      google_pubsub {
        project_id => "pj-becfr-monitoring-mgmt"
        topic => "f7_monitoring_topic_${environment}_alerting_eck"
        subscription => "f7_monitoring_subscription_${environment}_alerting_eck"
        json_key_file => "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash-sa.json"
        codec => "json"
      }
    }
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "application_code" => "a-alerting-eck"
    "leanix_id" => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "workfront_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "alerts-%%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    hosts => [ "${url}" ]
    user => "elastic"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    password => "${pwd}"
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt"
  }
}
```

Now the variable substitution with their values:

> export url=google.com
> export pwd=HjkTdddddss
> export environment=dev

`envsubst < logs_alerts_pubsub.conf`

```yaml
input {
      google_pubsub {
        project_id => "pj-becfr-monitoring-mgmt"
        topic => "f7_monitoring_topic_dev_alerting_eck"
        subscription => "f7_monitoring_subscription_dev_alerting_eck"
        json_key_file => "/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash-sa.json"
        codec => "json"
      }
    }
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => { "application_code" => "a-alerting-eck"
    "leanix_id" => "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
    "workfront_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "alerts-%%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
    hosts => [ "google.com" ]
    user => "elastic"
    ssl => true
    ssl_certificate_verification => false
    password => "HjkTdddddss"
    cacert => "/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt"
  }
}
```

Now the formatting of the pipeline file as json string:
`jq -c -Rs "." <(envsubst < logs_alerts_pubsub.conf)`

```bash
"input {\n      google_pubsub {\n        project_id => \"pj-becfr-monitoring-mgmt\"\n        topic => \"f7_monitoring_topic_dev_alerting_eck\"\n        subscription => \"f7_monitoring_subscription_dev_alerting_eck\"\n        json_key_file => \"/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash-sa.json\"\n        codec => \"json\"\n      }\n    }\nfilter {\n  mutate {\n    add_field => { \"application_code\" => \"a-alerting-eck\"\n    \"leanix_id\" => \"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx\"\n    \"workfront_id\" => \"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\"\n    }\n  }\n}\noutput {\n  elasticsearch {\n    index => \"alerts-%%{+yyyy.MM.dd}\"\n    hosts => [ \"google.com\" ]\n    user => \"elastic\"\n    ssl => true\n    ssl_certificate_verification => false\n    password => \"HjkTdddddss\"\n    cacert => \"/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt\"\n  }\n}"
```